# How to configure SSL / HTTPS on Spring?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, https

I'm working on a Spring Java app that requires HTTPS, and I followed [Spring's guide to configure SSL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl).

My application.properties file contains the following:

```
server.port = 8443
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password = password
server.ssl.key-password = password
server.ssl.keyStoreType = JCEKS
server.ssl.keyAlias = alias
```

When the app is run, the console outputs `Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (https)`, but any request to the server results in a `0 NO RESPONSE` status.

What am I missing?

Comment: All requests are being made with _https://_.

Comment: Also I am guessing the last two property names should instead by `key-store-type` and `key-alias` respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem seems to be the specified encryption algorithm. I was generating the key using `keytool`, with `-keyalg AES`. Changed it to use RSA with `-keyalg RSA` and it works now.

Comment: SSL certificates use assymmetic encryption, so perhaps explains why AES does not work. Nice work and answer.