# Enable HTTP2 with Tomcat in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, tomcat, http2

*Tomcat 8.5*, which will be the default in *Spring Boot 1.4*, supports **HTTP/2**.

How can **HTTP/2** be enabled in a *Spring Boot* application?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The most elegant and best-performing way to enable `HTTP/2` with a Spring Boot application follows here.

First, as mentioned in Andy Wilkinson's answer, you need to enable HTTP/2 at Tomcat level:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer tomcatCustomizer() {
    return (container) -> {
        if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                    .addConnectorCustomizers((connector) -> {
                connector.addUpgradeProtocol(new Http2Protocol());
            });
        }
    };
}
```

In case you are not using an embedded Tomcat, you can set up HTTP/2 listening like this:

```
<Connector port="5080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000">
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
</Connector>
```

*Remember that you need Tomcat >= 8.5.*

Then, you should use `HAProxy` *(version >= 1.7)* in front of Tomcat to take care of encryption.

The client will speak https to HAProxy, and HAProxy will speak cleartext HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 to the backend, as the client requested.
There will be no unnecessary protocol translations.

The matching HAProxy-configuration is here:

```
# Create PEM: cat cert.crt cert.key ca.crt > /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem

global
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tls-tickets force-tlsv12
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    timeout connect 10000ms
    timeout client 60000ms
    timeout server 60000ms

frontend fe_https
    mode tcp
    rspadd Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=31536000;\ includeSubDomains;\ preload
    rspadd X-Frame-Options:\ DENY
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
    default_backend be_http

backend be_http
    mode tcp
    server domain 127.0.0.1:8080
    # compression algo gzip # does not work in mode "tcp"
    # compression type text/html text/css text/javascript application/json
```

**Edit 2019**

I face two problems when using mode "tcp"

- Compression does not work, since it depends on mode http. So the backend has to take care of it
- The backend can not see the client's IP-address. Probably I need NAT. Still investigating...

Generally, since haproxy proxies a lower level tcp connection, there is no access to any http stuff

Comment: Is there a way to not use HAproxy? Spring boot and tomcat couldn't just handle encription and the upgrade?

Comment: Check this link https://readlearncode.com/configure-tomcat-9-for-http2/ posted by Alex above.

Comment: I was planning to use it with embedded tomcat of spring which is 8.5. I think I will try Undertow it is supposed to have support for http2

Comment: Embedded Tomcat does also support http2, and ssl can be configured like this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl. If you do that, and add the connector.addUpgradeProtocol(new Http2Protocol()); I believed it should work.

Comment: Do you have source about embedded tomcat (8.5) support of http2? I read something about tomcat native. I havent been able to set up tomcat yet.

Comment: I have checked with spring boot 2.2.4, embedded tomcat 9.x  and JAVA8. By configuring server.http2.enabled=true and setting up the java.library.path to tomcat native bin path, I am able to see the APIs running on HTTP2.

Answer (score 64):

In [Spring Boot 2.1 and above](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.http2.enabled) it is as simple as adding this property to your *.properties* (or *.yml*) file:

```
server.http2.enabled=true
```

You can also do it programmatically like this (in one of your configuration classes):

```java
@Bean
public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory tomcatCustomizer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> connector.addUpgradeProtocol(new Http2Protocol()));
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: this only works when JDK 9 or above is used.  I have been trying to enable it for my spring boot service running in a docker container but it does not work . Check here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html

Comment: It just enables HTTP2, but any configuration in application.yml is not passed to Http2Protocol. I could not find any other solution than java self implemented config, that forwards server.* properties to Http2Protocol.

Answer (score 37):

You need to add the HTTP 2 upgrade protocol to Tomcat's connector. You can do that by customizing the embedded Tomcat container:

#### Java 8:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer tomcatCustomizer() {
    return (container) -> {
        if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                    .addConnectorCustomizers((connector) -> {
                connector.addUpgradeProtocol(new Http2Protocol());
            });
        }
    };
}
```

#### Java 7:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer tomcatCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                        .addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
                    @Override
                    public void customize(Connector connector) {
                        connector.addUpgradeProtocol(new Http2Protocol());
                    }

                });
            }
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Is there anything else that needs to be done apart of running Tomcat with https? (I did enable it for localhost by following this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404579/how-to-set-up-ssl-tls-https-on-spring-boot-using-aes-256). But in Chrome's network debugger I see everything is still served via http/1.1

Comment: `h2c` will work as-is but not many (any?) browsers support it. If you want it to work securely (`h2`), you'll need to jump through some hoops with Tomcat Native.

Comment: That's a strange way to ask for more help. I'm done here.

Comment: Just to add that Tomcat 9 supports HTTP2 with a few configuration in the server.xml file. https://readlearncode.com/configure-tomcat-9-for-http2/

Comment: I have a potentially very dumb question.  Several times, I have seen "include this bean" in relation to Spring Boot ... but I have not been able to figure out what file to open/create before I paste the bean.

Comment: Just add snippet above in a class annotated with @Configuration of spring framework

Comment: @AndyWilkinson i tried your solution and subsequently added a new TLS 1.2 self signed certificate but still my browser is using http 1.1. Is there a problem with embedded tomcat?

Comment: I can’t say without some more information. Why not add a question of your own, providing as much information as you can?

Answer (score 15):

In Spring Boot 2 you first need a certificate - it can by generated like this:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias my-the-best-api -keystore c:\tmp\keystore.store -storepass secret -validity 3650 -keysize 2048
```

Than you just need to add this certificate to classpath and add needed properties to application.properties:

```
server.http2.enabled=true
server.port = 8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=secret
```

Comment: Worth noting that Spring Boot 2.0.x uses Tomcat 8.5, so if using embedded Tomcat, you still need to configure the path to `libtcnative` as noted in the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-configure-http2-tomcat).  Spring Boot 2.1.x will ship with Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 7):

Spring Boot 2.2.0+ ships by default with Tomcat 9.0.x which supports HTTP/2 out of the box when using JDK 9 or later. [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-http2-tomcat)