# How to enable and use Cipher Suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA in Java v1.8

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to establish connection over ssl. The client has only enabled **TLSv1.0** and supports limited number of cipher suites mentioned below:

- TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

I am running the server on **Java 1.8.0_151-b12**. When client is requesting to establish SSL connection I see following exception on server console:
https-jsse-nio-9080-exec-8, fatal: engine already closed.
Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

I have tried the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength and it didn't worked.

Is there a way to enable these cipher suite in Java v1.8?

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` and `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` (when Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy file is in place) [should be supported by Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider). What kind of server are you using; is there any custom SSL handling code on the server side that could play a part here?

Comment: Does the server have configured (or created) a keystore containing an RSA privatekey with suitable certificate or chain?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I am using SpringBoot v1.5.3 + Tomcat v8.5.14. There isn't any custom SSL handling code on the server side.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I have used keyalg as RSA while creating the cert. Is there a way to specify cipher suites while creating cert? Also, does it matters if I have created the cert before placing unlimited strength policy jars?

Comment: @MickMnemonic+ I didn't notice immediately, but 8u151 (and 152, and j9) finally removed the silly policy-files requirement, now all you need is a simple text edit in JRE/lib/security/java.security -- see the release notes. But Oracle nonbeta releases shouldn't have a -b(num) element; only OpenJDK does that and OpenJDK never had the policy-files misfeature in the first place. Plus even if you have the policy restriction it only affects AES256; AES128 and 3DES are allowed even with the restriction in place.

Comment: s_r: If you created a _cert_ from a CSR, that can't alter the key or its type in any way and `-keyalg` is ignored. If you created a _keypair_ (with its default selfsigned cert) then yes RSA is correct, but it needs to be in the correct keystore and depending on your config the correct alias, which you didn't mention. BTW Tomcat 8.5 (and 9) allows more flexible SSL configuration not limited to the traditional JKS method, but JKS still works; look at your https `Connector` element including any nested `SSLHostConfig` and `Certificate` in `server.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dave_thompson_085 Thanks for looking into my query. I was able to resolve this problem and here are the steps,

1. Print all Java DefaultCipherSuites & SupportedCipherSuites and look for the one needed.
2. If found then add the cipher suite name on SpringBoot configuration file as described here,
   [How to set up SSL (TLS) / HTTPS on Spring Boot using AES-256?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404579/how-to-set-up-ssl-tls-https-on-spring-boot-using-aes-256)